# Lazy load startup applications

Tags: startup-applications

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I have a few startup applications - Dropbox, Transmission, a few custom scripts. These stretch the login time to ~10 -15 seconds (an old machine here).

I do not need to start these immediately at login. Is there a way to lazy load these applications?

Answer (score 3):

The way I finally did was

Startup Applications -> Add -> Command

```
bash -c "sleep 10 && path/to/program_or_script"
```

Complete the name and comments and hit save.

example: start dropbox one minute after login (Disable autostart in dropbox preferences)

```
bash -c "sleep 60 && dropbox start -i"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a small bash script that will kick off those programs, then create a startup script that calls it via `at`. So, create your bash script, something like lazy-startup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
transmission
dropbox
other scripts
```

Then create your kickoff script lazy-startup-kickoff.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
at -f /path/to/lazy-startup.sh now + 5 minutes
```